# How to get byte array as return from C byte pointer in JNA

Tags: c++, jna

I am using JNA for access to native functions. In my native function one my method is returning byte pointer. How could I get same byte array values as return in JNA? I have tried by getting as string and convert it to bytes but it's not working.

This is my code:

```
BYTE* GetImageDate(); // in C++
```

Answer (score 1):

Return a pointer, then use [`Pointer.getByteArray(0, size)`](http://twall.github.io/jna/4.1.0/com/sun/jna/Pointer.html#getByteArray(long,%20int)) to extract `size` bytes from the corresponding memory location.

Note that you'll have to somehow figure out what `size` is, unless the function is returning a NUL-terminated C string.